# Cambiar el valor de un hidden incrustado en la columna de una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una forma en *HTML* y *JavaScript*. Necesito por código asignar a cada renglón de una tabla, que tienen *estatus 1*, una subdirección mediante un combo (resuelta esta parte).

El problema es que requiero duplicar cualquier renglón usando un botón para que este mismo renglón duplicado (resuelto), tenga *estatus 2* para poder diferenciarlos (parte no resuelta). Utilizo un *hidden* donde guardo el estatus y está incrustado en la columna de una tabla.

El problema es que no encuentro cómo referenciar el renglón donde oprimo el botón *duplicar* para cambiar su valor:

El botón llama a esta función *JavaScript*:

```
function duplica_numeral(nI,numeral_id,of_au_id,au_id){

    //alert("Entro a duplicar numeral "  );
    var oTabla  = document.getElementById("Tab_Numerales");
    var nFilas  = oTabla.rows.length;
    var row     = document.getElementById("numeral"+nI); // find row to copy
    var clone   = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id    = "numeral"+nFilas; // change id or other attributes/contents
    clone.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].id = "comboAtencion" + nFilas;
    alert("Before change to c ( hidNumeral has value 'a' "  ); // This line runs
    clone.getElementById('hidNumeral').value = 'c'; // this line is incorrect, why ??
    alert("after change to c "  ); // This line does not run  
}
```

Código *HTML*:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" id="Tab_Numerales" >
<tr height="25%" bgcolor="<?php echo $vcolor; ?>" 
 name="numeral<?echo$i;?>" id="numeral<?echo$i;?>">
    <td align="center" class="rows"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td align="center" class="rows"><?php echo $row['numeral']; ?></td>
    <td align="center" class="rows"><input name="hidNumeral" type="text" id="hidNumeral"
```

Quiero poner `table hidnumeral` en *estatus 2*.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar JavaScript para ello, específicamente `setAttribute()` sobre el elemento clonado. Usando tu código como ejemplo:

```
function duplica_numeral(nI,numeral_id,of_au_id,au_id){
  var oTabla  = document.getElementById("Tab_Numerales");
  var nFilas  = oTabla.rows.length;
  var clone   = document.getElementById("numeral"+nI).cloneNode(true);
  clone.id    = "numeral"+nFilas;
  console.log(clone);
  clone.children[2].children[0].value = '2';  //Asigna valor al INPUT
  clone.setAttribute("hidnumeral", nI + 1); //Asigna valor a la propiedad
  console.log(clone);
}
```

Recomiendo usar `console.log()` en lugar de `alert()` puesto que te da toda la definición del objeto al que mandas a log y alert solamente regresaría el string `[object]` o similar.

Aquí agrego un ejemplo mínimo y verificable :)

```js
var referencia = document.getElementById("numeral_1");
var tablaPadre = referencia.parentNode
var clone = referencia.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "numeral" + 2;
clone.children[1].children[0].value = 'MAMBO 2!!';
tablaPadre.appendChild(clone);
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" id="Tab_Numerales">
  <tr height="25%" bgcolor="pink" name="numeral1" id="numeral_1">
    <td align="center" class="rows">1</td>
    <td align="center" class="rows"><input name="hidNumeral" type="text" id="hidNumeral_1" value="Mambo!" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: De una forma muy básica se hace con `document.getElementById("MiID").value = "El valor que quiero";` pero me parece que estaba entendiendo tu necesidad de una forma distinta. Actualicé mi ejemplo para ajustarse a lo que necesitas y dejo 2 asignaciones por si las dudas.

Comment: Gracias , lo que quiero es que el value de hidnumeral cambia a '2' , no el name si fuera por objetos sería algo así      tabla.columna.hidnumeral.value = '2', el problema es que no se como ponerlo en el DOM utilizando javascript.   he intentado con los siguientes códigos pero no me han funcionado //clone.getElementById('hidNumeral').setAttribute('value' , '2');
//clone.getElementById('hidNumeral').text = '2';
// clone.getElementById('hidNumeral').set({value:'2'}); 
//clone.getElementById('hidNumeral').attr("value", "2");